How do I rotate a 3d Object around X axis
I need to have a train cart go down a track and stop at a station, then it needs to rotate upside down around the X axis, stop then rotate back.
I've tried using, setRotation functions, but they don't work and keep saying "cannot make a static referance to the non static method.
how should I set up this model to make the rotation occur smoothly
So I tried using the setRotation functions, tried my3Dobject.setRotation()
tried using state charts to do it, could only get it to continuously spin, tried seize and the rotate.

You need to add the animation element to a Group. You can then rotate that group around the axis you need, including the x-axis.
(There is no other way)

The rotationX is working now.  What would be the best way to change the RotationX value from 0 to 180 at a rate of 3 deg / sec at a specific state in a statechart? I tried making a variable V_RotationX and updating the values with time functions, but so far was not able to get it right

Pls always open new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a forum but is a pure Q&A place, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
